# i3 3850k stuck at max freqeuency (100% C0)

Tags: 18.04, power-management, cpu, tlp

For the past few days my PC has been stuck at max frequency. My Specs
Ubuntu 18.04 Server (headless)
i3-8350k
ROG Strix z370 Gaming Mobo with Wifi
32GB RAM

I've tried using tlp to enable powersave mode to downclock when idle, but nothing works. i7z shows my cores stuck in C0 mode:

```
 Real Current Frequency 4011.98 MHz [100.18 x 40.05] (Max of below)
    Core [core-id]  :Actual Freq (Mult.)      C0%   Halt(C1)%  C3 %   C6 %  Temp      VCore
    Core 1 [0]:       4011.98 (40.05x)       100       0       0       0    53      1.1639
    Core 2 [1]:       4011.98 (40.05x)       100       0       0       0    55      1.1639
    Core 3 [2]:       4011.98 (40.05x)       100       0       0       0    56      1.1639
    Core 4 [3]:       4011.97 (40.05x)       100       0       0       0    55      1.1639
```

I can manually force my CPU to 800Mhz or higher, but I would really like to have dynamic clocks during low usage periods, which is common because this PC is used as a router for my network.

My output of /etc/default/tlp.conf

```
sudo tlp-stat -c
```

--- TLP 1.1 --------------------------------------------

```
+++ Configured Settings: /etc/default/tlp
TLP_ENABLE=1
TLP_DEFAULT_MODE=AC
TLP_PERSISTENT_DEFAULT=0
DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_AC=0
DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_BAT=2
MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_AC=15
MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_BAT=60
CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_AC=powersave
CPU_SCALING_MIN_FREQ_ON_AC=20
CPU_SCALING_MAX_FREQ_ON_AC=100
CPU_HWP_ON_AC=power
CPU_HWP_ON_BAT=balance_power
CPU_MIN_PERF_ON_AC=0
CPU_MAX_PERF_ON_AC=100
CPU_BOOST_ON_AC=0
SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_AC=1
SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_BAT=1
NMI_WATCHDOG=0
ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_AC=balance-power
ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_BAT=power
DISK_DEVICES="sda sdb"
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_AC="254 50"
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_BAT="128 128"
DISK_SPINDOWN_TIMEOUT_ON_AC="0 300"
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_AC="med_power_with_dipm max_performance"
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_BAT="med_power_with_dipm min_power"
AHCI_RUNTIME_PM_TIMEOUT=15
PCIE_ASPM_ON_AC=performance
PCIE_ASPM_ON_BAT=powersave
RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_AC=high
RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_BAT=low
RADEON_DPM_STATE_ON_AC=performance
RADEON_DPM_STATE_ON_BAT=battery
RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_AC=auto
RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_BAT=auto
WIFI_PWR_ON_AC=off
WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=on
WOL_DISABLE=Y
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_AC=0
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=1
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_CONTROLLER=Y
BAY_POWEROFF_ON_AC=0
BAY_POWEROFF_ON_BAT=0
BAY_DEVICE="sr0"
RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC=on
RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT=auto
USB_AUTOSUSPEND=1
USB_BLACKLIST_BTUSB=0
USB_BLACKLIST_PHONE=0
USB_BLACKLIST_PRINTER=1
USB_BLACKLIST_WWAN=1
RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP=0

sudo tlp-stat -s
--- TLP 1.1 --------------------------------------------

+++ System Info
System         = System manufacturer System Version System Product Name
BIOS           = 1002
Release        = Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Kernel         = 4.15.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 10 17:58:07 UTC 2018 x86_64
/proc/cmdline  = BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-32-generic 
Init system    = systemd v237
Boot mode      = UEFI

+++ TLP Status
State          = enabled
Last run       = 05:43:39 PM,    306 sec(s) ago
Mode           = AC
Power source   = unknown
```

I would really like my CPU to downclock when idle, which it is not longer doing. Everytime I look in i7z or powertop, C0 is 100% and poll in powertop is also near 100%. Meanwhile Htop shows very little CPU use on any core.

I'm sure when I installed the server dynamic frequency was working, but now it seems to be broken.

Also, I've made sure the BIOS has all power save and C-State functions enabled. I don't know what else to try.

Comment: 8th generation processors are very new. Just as a test, try kernel [4.18](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.18/). Myself, I wouldn't use tlp in this application.

Comment: I'm using ukuu to download 4.18.1, will reboot soon and post back.

Comment: Just upgraded to 4.18.1 using ukuu, no change unfortunately. I also purged tlp as well.

Comment: Just read about the poll stat in powertop here: https://vatikaharlalka.wordpress.com/2015/06/15/cpu-idle-states/ They say poll is used for staying in C0 because system does not want to go to powersave as it thinks heavy work is coming up and should not lower frequency. This is a real problem for me power use is much too high at idle.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I have tuned installed, and once I stopped the service my CPU will now enter powersave modes. Note to others: tuned will max your CPU and keep it there. Use it with caution.

Idle CPU temps went from 55C to 40C with tuned disabled.